# The better algorithm for Modular Exponentiation on secp256k1/r1

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, secp256k1

I know Modular Exponentiation ($r = b^e \bmod m$) is important for RSA, and I can find some algorithm that if e is expressed in binary form (for exp: )--in such way for a n-bit long e, one can expect ~1.5n rounds multiply modular operation.

I am working on making a public key recovery methodology for ECC like secp256k1/r1. There is a very efficient implementation in the secp256k1 lib, but that was coded in ASM code--hard to understand. But at least I know the 1st step--you need to recover the $ry$ from the $rx$ (i.e. r of the signature). It is very easy to get $ry^2$ from $rx$, but the next I will need to do square root modular--which can be converted to the exponentiation modular on the field, that is $e= (p+1)/4.$

OK, so now questions are:

1. Is there a better algorithm other than the usual Modular Exponentiation to calculate the ($r = b^e \bmod m$)?
2. Or alternatively, is there any short-cut algorithm specifically for secp256k1 that I don’t need run Modular Exponentiation at all and still be able to recover the $ry$ from $rx$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no substitute for modular multiplication in the question's cryptosystems. Some languages like Python make that easy for educational purposes, *only*.

In RSA and DSA, and to a lesser degree ECC crypto on [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1) or [secp256r1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.2), one needs to compute $b^e\bmod m$ for large $e$. The fastest algorithms (e.g. [sliding window exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Sliding-window_method)) perform about $\log_2 e$ modular squaring and like $\approx0.2\,\log_2 e$ modular multiplications. However there are other algorithms only marginally more costly (e.g. [Montgomery's ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Montgomery%27s_ladder_technique)) that may be better from the standpoint of security against side channels.

Each modular multiplication or squaring modulo $m$, for the above or (in ECC) point addition or multiplication by a scalar, has computational cost growing at most like $(\log m)^2$ when using the algorithms learned in primary school adapted to computer words instead of digits. That can be lowered to $(\log m)^{\approx1.6}$ with [Karatsuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) or $(\log m)^{\approx1.5}$ with [Toom-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication), but in ECC the modulus $m$ is not large enough that it pays much ($m$ is a 'only' some hundreds bit in ECC, rather than some thousands in RSA/DSA).

When developing signature or encryption using [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1) or [secp256r1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.2) from scratch for educational purposes, there typically are phases:

- Getting something that works, by building [point addition and doubling in Cartesian coordinates](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.1) on top of modular multiplication, then point multiplication, then signature or/and encryption.
- Getting it to work much faster by using a better representation of point, e.g. projective coordinates (which allows to deffer the costly modular inversion until the end of point multiplication)
- Getting it to work securely, which is very hard and typically requires rewriting a lot of things from the grounds up.
- Performance optimizations. These can be attempted at any stage, but ponder the saying "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

---

Some online references on modular multiplication and exponentiation (not ECC):

- Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone's [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) (CRC press, 1996), especially sections [14.3](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf#page=10) and [14.6](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf#page=24).
- Richard Brent and Paul Zimmermann's [Modern Computer Arithmetic](https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/mca/pub226.html) (Cambridge University press, 2010), especially sections [2.4](https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/mca/mca-cup-0.5.9.pdf#section.2.4) and [2.6](https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/mca/mca-cup-0.5.9.pdf#section.2.6).